Are these 3 versions of the Axiom of Infinity equivalent
I am wondering about three variants on the Axiom of Infinity I have come across; in particular, I would like to know if the "weakest" of these could be used to prove the others.
The (apparently) weakest is stated in Godel's monograph on the consistency of the continuum hypothesis, where he presents (in NBG set theory) axiom C1 [the Axiom of Infinity] as
"There exists a set $a$ such that $a$ is not empty, and for all sets $x \in a$ there exists a set $y$ such that $y \in a$ and $x$ is a proper subset of $y$."
I was trying to get from this axiom to showing that with the von Neumann formulation of the integers
$0 \equiv \emptyset, \forall n>0 (n \equiv \bigcup_{m<n} n)$
the set of all such integers
is indeed a set.
Perhaps bit stronger than the above axiom C1 is an axiom ascribed [by Suppes in his book Axiomatic Set Theory] to Zermelo (1908)]: "There exists a set $a$ such that $a$ contains the empty set $\emptyset$, and for all sets $x \in a$ there exists a set $y$ such that $y \in a$ and $x$ is a proper subset of $y$."
Let's refer to this as Zermelo's axiom of infinity.  I say this is perhaps stronger because obviously such a set would also satisfy the condition of axiom C1.  It supports Zermlo's formulation of the integers as $ 0 \equiv \emptyset $ and for $n>0$, $n \equiv $ the set containing $n-1$.
Finally, we have the axiom of infinity as stated by Suppes on page 138 of the Dover edition:
"There exists a set $A$ such that $A$ contains the empty set $\emptyset$, and for all sets $B \in A$ the union of $B$ with the set containing $B$ is also in $A$."  This obviously supports the idea that the usual (von Neumann) formulation of the integers constitutes a set, because that is precisely what this axiom states.
My question is, can one prove, from axiom C1, either Zermelo's form or the desired "the integers are a set" form of the axiom of infinity?
If not, can Zermelo's form of the axiom be used to prove the (von Neumann) integers constitute a set?

What other axioms are you using? E.g. it's easy to get from C1 to usual infinity if you have both replacement and choice.

Your statement of the first two versions seems wrong to me: "for all sets $x \in a$ there exists a set $y$ such that $y \in a$ and $x$ is a subset of $y$" is vacuously true, isn't it? You can just take $y = x$.

It was probably meant to be $y\subsetneq x$, see this brief mention on Wikipedia.

... suggested fix: I think you need to say "proper subset". Please be more careful! (Thanks to @SassatelliGiulio for providing a link while I was typing this comment.)

@Rob Arthan - you are right, of course, it was meant to be "x is an element of y". Editing now. Wait - just checked Godel paper; it is "x is a proper subset of y."

It can't be "is an element of $y$", because that version of the axiom, together with the axiom of (countable dependent) choice, would contradict the Axiom of Foundation. I think the previous commenters are correct that it is supposed to be "and $x$ is a proper subset of $y$".

@Noah Schweber We have replacement but not choice.

@ArturoMagidin I don't believe that $x\in y$ is inconsistent with ZFC, in fact I'd say that $\omega$ a set such that for all $x\in \omega$ there is some $y\in \omega$ such that $x\in y$ (and $x\subsetneq y$).

This is the typical sort of argument that goes from a "weak" axiom like "there is an infinite set" to "$\omega$ exists". I don't think it needs choice.

There is a sketch of the proof in the above referenced Wikipedia article. Can someone expand this out/fill in the gaps. Choice is not mentioned. And the proof assumes the weakest version.

To get from C1 to Zermelo, it seems to me all you have to do is use Pairing on $\varnothing$ to get ${\varnothing}$, then use Pairing on this and $a$ to get ${{\varnothing}, a}$, and finally use Union/Union+Separation (depending on how Union is formulated) to get ${\varnothing}\cup a$.
